# Why is a variable not being set after xmlhttp.responseText?

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, xmlhttprequest

When validating a send-fax form, I'm checking to see if a fax has already been sent with our software fax package.  It's a simple query to a table performed by a script, which returns some text if a previous fax exists, or blank if not.

I'm finding that the flag_stop_fax variable is still set to zero, even when I have some response text (ex: "A fax has already been sent.").

```
flag_stop_fax = 0;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
    {
        var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (response!='')
        {
            flag_stop_fax = 1;
            alert(response);
        }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open('GET','/check_for_active_fax.php?fax_number=' + fax_number + '&t='+Math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.send();

alert(flag_stop_fax); // shows "0" even when I have a non-blank response from xmlhttp.responseText
```

There is some other validation bits that go along with this, but the script above hopefully illustrates the problem.   I don't use the 't' variable for anything - this is just a safeguard against browser caching.

So why isn't my flag_stop_fax getting set to 0?

Comment: AJAX is `Asynchronous`. That alert you commented next to runs before the callback code.

Comment: Answer this question first - What does the A in Ajax stand for?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand that AJAX is asynchronous. When you execute `xmlhttp.send();`, your request is sent and code execution continues, so the next thing that is run is:

```
alert(flag_stop_fax);
```

At this time, `flag_stop_fax` is still zero, because the request haven't completed yet.

The callback function you specified for `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` will only run **when the request was completed**. Execution is not sequential here. It is something like:

1. `xmlhttp.send();` - the request has been started
2. `alert(flag_stop_fax);` - the variable is alerted

   ...
   ...
   (some time later, when the server answered)

   `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` is executed, changing the `flag_stop_fax` variable.

Comment: So is there not a way to stop form submission if the check returns true (ie, response is not blank)?

Comment: There is a way. You have to stop form submission. Wait for the response. And if the response is true, submit the form. Whatever you want to do, you have to do it in the callback, because you cannot know when will your request finish.

Comment: No. Simply check the variable in the callback (`xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`). And submit the form if necessary. (at first this is a concept that is hard to understand, you have to learn to think in an asynchronous way :) - be patient, sit back and think through what I have written, then do some searches on it)

Comment: Since I've already submitted the form (that's where this bit is happening) do I need to rewrite my validation completely?   I'm alerting the response text - but the return false; I added is ignored.  Should I post up my entire validation function?   I get that the ajax bit happens separate from the rest - just not sure how to link them.

Comment: I can't show the working script since its behind firewall, but here's the function I'm using to validate.  

http://jsfiddle.net/wTwTG/